# Converting asp.net membership database to Sql Server Compact 4.0

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption, asp.net-membership

I have an Asp.Net MVC 3 website that uses asp.net membership services for authentication.  The membership database has been running on Sql Server Express 2008 and I am attempting to convert it to Sql Sever Compact 4.0.

Following the instructions [here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) I have created the Sql Server Compact 4.0 database. I used the code from [here](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/) to switch the membership provider in the MVC app.

Using the new provider and database I am able to successfully create new users and log in using the new user's password.  However, I am not able to login to any of the users that previously existed in the Sql Server Express database.  I am able to browse the new database and have verified that the users are all there, so I believe the problem is somehow related to not being able to successfully access the encrypted passwords that had been previously created.  I really don't want to have all of the existing users change their passwords.  Can anyone shed some light as to how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible it has something to do with the ApplicationName property in the web.config file?

See this blog post from ScottGu for more information:

> [Always set the "applicationName" property when configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and other Providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx)